# Parse HTML with JavaScript&jQuery - replace class names with random characters

Tags: javascript, python, html, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse HTML page with additional JavaScript or jQuery get class names and than replace it with random characters. I can easily extract class names but replacing it causes trouble. I have this code so far:

```
class_ids = [tag.split() for tag in re.findall(r'class=(?:"|\')([a-zA-Z0-9-_\s]+)(?:"|\')', html_page)]
class_ids = set([item for sublist in class_ids for item in sublist])
```

For each class I'll generate corresponding random characters class name (exp.  **footer : sjrh13li**). Simply replacing **footer** string through file will also replace it in body text, also class names like **title** will also convert tag `<title></title>` to `<cjir4331></cjir4331>`. I've tried to replace whole line like `class="title"` => `class="cjir4331"` but this doesn't solve problems like `class="title huge"` because I need to detect classes **title** and **huge** separately and replace them. HTML code is combined with JavaScript code so `document.getElementsByClassName('someClass')` must be converted to  document.getElementsByClassName('noleretko4356').

Is there any way around this?

Comment: That's a pretty complex request for a pretty useless result. Are you only doing this to obfuscate CSS?

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Yeah...I know it's useless. Can't explain it to my boss :) Well yes but I can't use Javascript to obfuscate CSS and it has to be random.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using some sort of HTML parser - parsing HTML with regexp's never works out well.

Comment: Well...I've found this [link](http://htmlmuncher.com/). Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to obfuscate your code before launching it in production ? Do you need to preserve the css associated with those elements ?

Does something like this helps you ?

https://jsfiddle.net/p36pre5o/6/

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var guid = generateUUID();
    $('.test').removeClass('test').addClass(guid);
});
```

This code will find all elements with a class test and replace it with a random guid.